# Reattach attribute table to Spatial Polygon to make Spatial Polygon Dataframe

Tags: r, polygon, geospatial, coercion, spatial-data-frame

I have built a web app using Shiny and Leaflet, but it renders very slowly because the Spatial Polygon DataFrame (merge.proj) that is being added to the map is 20,000 polygons. I may try to allow the user to view only certain neighborhoods at a time as a fix, but first I thought I'd simplify polygons to see how much that sped up the process.

My understanding is that simplifying polygons reduces # of vertices etc and gives you a Spatial Polygon, which loses the attribute table. I was hoping to then reattach the attribute table and re-create a Spatial Polygon Dataframe that is hopefully reduced in size.

However, the code is erroring and all the help I can find online just shows how to do this when making the Spatial Polygon and dataframe from scratch, and I'm having trouble applying what they did to my data ([see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141469/how-to-convert-a-spatialpolygon-to-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe-and-add-a-column-t)). The error says that my polygon IDs and row.names don't match, but they both originally came from the same Spatial Polygon Dataframe so I'm confused. And I'm not sure how to manually manipulate things so they match.

I am pasting below the error and the code I currently have. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
# For faster plotting, simplify polygons
merge.simplify <- gSimplify(merge.proj,0.1,topologyPreserve = T)

# Create a dataframe
merge.df <- data.frame(merge.proj@data)

# Do coercion to SPDF
merge.spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(merge.simplify, merge.df)
```

ERROR: Error in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(merge.simplify, merge.df) : 
  row.names of data and Polygons IDs do not match

Comment: If you've been really careful to ensure the row order hasn't changed, just supply `match.id = FALSE` to `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked. Would you mind explaining what saying match.id = FALSE is doing to make that work?

Comment: Was something not clear in `?SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`?

Comment: I'm new to this and often times those help pages are too dense with vocab or underlying mechanisms I don't understand that it makes it difficult to interpret. I was just wondering if a person explaining it would bring more clarity. But I did look at the help page and I think I get the gist of it. Thanks!

Comment: We understand that the documentation can be unhelpful, but it's easiest for us to help you if start by explaining what in the docs doesn't make sense to you, otherwise we're likely (being far too used to these functions ourselves) to repeat the documentation